# How to add a specific number of characters to the end of string in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-length, maxlength

I am using the Pandas library within Python and I am trying to increase the length of a column with text in it to all be the same length. I am trying to do this by adding a specific character (this will be white space normally, in this example I will use "_") a number of times until it reaches the maximum length of that column.

For example:

**Col1_Before**

```
A
B
A1R
B2
AABB4
```

**Col1_After**

```
A____
B____
A1R__
B2___
AABB4
```

So far I have got this far (using the above table as the example). It is the next part (and the part that does it that I am stuck on).

```
df['Col1_Max'] = df.Col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
df['Col1_Len'] = df.Col1.map(lambda x: len(x))
df['Difference_Len'] = df ['Col1_Max'] - df ['Col1_Len']
```

I may have not explained myself well as I am still learning. If this is confusing let me know and I will clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating extra columns:

```
In [63]: data
Out[63]: 
    Col1
0      A
1      B
2    A1R
3     B2
4  AABB4

In [64]: max_length = data.Col1.map(len).max()

In [65]: data.Col1 = data.Col1.apply(lambda x: x + '_'*(max_length - len(x)))

In [66]: data
Out[66]: 
    Col1
0  A____
1  B____
2  A1R__
3  B2___
4  AABB4
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Added this in as a function to run on multiple columns at once and it worked a charm.

Answer (score 7):

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A1R', 'B2', 'AABB4'])
```

***solution***
use `str.ljust`

```
m = s.str.len().max()
s.str.ljust(m, '_')

0    A____
1    B____
2    A1R__
3    B2___
4    AABB4
dtype: object
```

---

***for your case***

```
m = df.Col1.str.len().max()
df.Col1 = df.Col1.ljust(m '_')
```

Comment: I did enjoy this answer. I had never considered using a series. I need to run the process multiple times which made me lean towards another solution.

Comment: @user3601042 in pandas, every column in a dataframe is a series. df.Col1 is a series.  This applies to your question like: `m = df.Col1.str.len().max()`  Then  `df.Col1 = df.Col1.str.ljust(m, '_')`  I don't care about the answer choice but I do care that you understand how to use this answer. I'll update my post.

Comment: This does make perfect sense. Your answer has changed my way of thinking. I understood every column was a series. However never in context to a problem and how to use that to construct a solution to such problem (downside of teaching yourself I guess). The answer has helped more then you probably realise. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the most pandas-like solution, but you can try the following:

```
col = np.array(["A", "B", "A1R", "B2", "AABB4"])
data = pd.DataFrame(col, columns=["Before"])
```

Now compute the maximum length, the list of individual lengths, and the differences:

```
max_ = data.Before.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
lengths_ = data.Before.map(lambda x: len(x))
diffs_ = max_ - lengths_
```

Create a new column called `After` adding the underscores, or any other character:

```
data["After"] = data["Before"] + ["_"*i for i in diffs_]
```

All this gives:

```
  Before  After
0      A  A____
1      B  B____
2    A1R  A1R__
3  AABB4  AABB4
```